# ANSI aggregate functions for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at ANSI aggregate functions for SQL and I can't find anything for strings. However each database seems to have its own, e.g GROUP_CONCAT and LISTAGG for MySQL and Oracle respectively, making portability a little difficult. Is there something I am missing? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL, optional Feature T625, “LISTAGG”.

Comment: Note that both PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server have implemented a `string_agg()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI has adopted `listagg()` as the standard.  I would not hold my breath waiting for other databases to change their function, though.

String aggregation was either viewed as unimportant originally or the committee could not decide on an appropriate standard.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRD%3DBR0JM8NFVpFsaY3ztvEupwhSKgDkHLCRLjpCMM1RAA%40mail.gmail.com) is an interesting perspective on the issue regarding Postgres.  I would caution reading too much into Oracle controlling the standards committee (unless the author has inside information).  IBM has also been very active and DB2 supports `listagg()`.

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate function for this is specified in the standard, `LISTAGG`; it was specified in SQL:2016 (ISO-9075-2:2016) in section 10.9 <aggregate function>. The fact each database has its own, is because it wasn't standardized in earlier versions of the standard.

Why it wasn't standardized before would be guessing to the reasons, deliberations and arguments of the standardization committee, which - as far as I know - are not publicly available, but either it wasn't considered important enough, or the committee couldn't come to an agreement on syntax and behaviour in earlier versions.