# MySQL: add column extracting changed history count

Tags: sql

Here is the table that I have

```
  SKU ID    Distributor
    
    1        A
    2        A
    2        B
    3        A
    3        B
    3        C
```

which I need to add a column that counts the changed history (basically pivot function in excel)

```
SKU ID  Distributor       Distributor Channge History
1         A                     1
2         A,B                   2
3         A,B,C                 3
```

very simple one, but I cannot figure it out. please help

```
select distinct(SKU ID),
       count count(distinct(Distributor)
from table
```

deleted all Distributor information

Comment: What is your actual SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?  SQL is a language, not an actual product.

Comment: What's the purpose of the last column and what's the logic how it will be filled? As your question currently stands, this column doesn't make any sense because it's totally identic to the first column. Please put more effort in explaining what you want to do. You wrote something about a history. What history are you talking about? Your table doesn't contain a history column (or at least, you haven't shown that)

Comment: `distinct` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Remove those extra parentheses and simply write select `distinct SKU ID, ...` and `count(distinct Distributor)` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for LISTAGG

```
SELECT "SKU ID" AS "SKU ID"
        , LISTAGG(Distributor,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY "SKU ID") AS "Distributor"
        , COUNT(Distributor) AS "Distributor Channge History" 
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS "SKU ID", 'A' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS "SKU ID", 'A' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS "SKU ID", 'B' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS "SKU ID", 'A' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS "SKU ID", 'B' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS "SKU ID", 'C' AS Distributor FROM dual) 
  GROUP BY "SKU ID"
```

| SKU ID | Distributor | Distributor Channge History |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | A,B | 2 |
| 3 | A,B,C | 3 |

Comment: How do you know they use a RDBMS that supports `LISTAGG`? Your answer uses a syntax for `Oracle` and will be totally useless if they don't use an Oracle DB.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

What if the "SKU ID" is actual not three but few thousands? 

Cannot add 

SELECT 1 AS "SKU ID", 'A' AS Distributor FROM dual
        UNION ALL

manually ㅠㅠ

Comment: @Jonas ANSI adopted LISTAGG as standard. see this post.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613921/ansi-aggregate-functions-for-sql) **stackoverflow 66613921**

Comment: @DerrickJWJeeWoongYang Use table and insert SKU data. and 
select * from YOURSKUTABLE;